# how to use linq to get dictionary object's variable

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have an object

```
class foo {
  public int bar;
  public string s;
}
```

that is in a dictionary

```
Dictionary<String, foo> mm = new Dictionary<String, foo>();
```

And I want to implmeent a method using LINQ to get all `values` of the dictonary and return a list of all the "bar" variables.  I figure this should be easy using linq, but i've not managed to fina relevant example.

```
public int[] getList() {
  return mm.Values.bar <- something like that but with linq
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Select` and `ToArray()`:

```
int[] bars = mm.Select(kv => kv.Value.bar).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 - but change `ToList` to `ToArray` (`public int[] getList()`).